# Scroll stops working after anchor animation

Tags: html, anchor, css-animations

[website link](https://www.alm-vision.com/)

In that website, go to "SERVICES" and click any mapping in the image. It goes to the specified anchor but it takes a bit of time before you can scroll away from it. This gets worse the smaller the screen is. How do I remove the lag time before I can scroll away from the anchored area?

Comment: you have to give scrollSpeed();

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the git messed the code up and created a duplicate of the animation code. That's the reason it got stuck